# Method to return specialised type of generic protocol swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, opaque-types

I have a generic protocol which has a method that returns the generic parameter. There are two implementations of the protocol that both have string as the return type. I want a method to build a particular instance similar to a class cluster based on some parameter. The method constrains the generic type but there is an error when trying to return:

"Cannot convert return expression of type StringReturn into return type T"

```
protocol GenericProtocol {

    typealias ReturnType

    func doSomething() -> ReturnType

}

struct StringReturn : GenericProtocol {

    func doSomething() -> String {
        return "first"
    }

}

struct AnotherStringReturn : GenericProtocol {

    func doSomething() -> String {
        return "another"
    }

}

func build<T : GenericProtocol where T.ReturnType == String>(param: String) -> T {

    if .. {
        return StringReturn()
    } else {
        return AnotherStringReturn
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is to use a generic function to create a instance of an object using Swift's Type Constraints.

Note the general syntax from Apple's documentation:

> ```
> func someFunction<T: SomeClass, U: SomeProtocol>(someT: T, someU: U) {
>   // function body goes here
> }
> ```

In you function, it's not possible to infer at the time of function execution what type `T` is because you aren't passing it to the function as a parameter, hence you can't say what type is the output.

If you want to use a generic function with type constraints you could add some `init` to your protocol and use a function like this:

```
func build<T : GenericProtocol where T.ReturnType == String>(object: T.Type, param: String) -> T {
  // Your code here
  return T.init()
}

let str = build(StringReturn.self, param: "name")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi this is nice but I want the function to decide what T ends up being, is this possible?

Comment: @LukeDeFeo If you want to return a object based on some conditions, I guess you can use a regular function with `GenericProtocol` as the returning type. The problem is that your protocol has an associated type, `ReturnType`, and it´s not possible to use it as a returning type.

Comment: Yeah so i wont be able to return Generic protocol as it has self requires and it can only be used as a generic constraint. Quite annoying, i find generic protocols to be almost useless :/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve using Opaque Types rather than Protocol generics at newest Swift versions.

Swift 5.3

> You can think of an opaque type like being the reverse of a generic type. Generic types let the code that calls a function pick the type for that function’s parameters and return value in a way that’s abstracted away from the function implementation. For example, the function in the following code returns a type that depends on its caller:

[Apple documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OpaqueTypes.html)

[**Example**](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/187/how-to-use-opaque-return-types-in-swift-5-1)

```
protocol Fighter { }
struct XWing: Fighter { }

func launchFighter() -> Fighter {
    XWing()
}

let red5 = launchFighter()
```

It needs keyword **some** before your protocol name:

```
func launchOpaqueFighter() -> some Fighter {
    XWing()
}
```